# Is it possible to get the specific index of occurence when working with period.apply?

Tags: r, xts, zoo

Assuming I worked with meteorological observations and wanted to know not only the daily maximum value but also the relevant timestamp, describing when this value was observed, is it possible to accomplish this without significant overhead, e.g. by setting some sort of parameter?

```r
library(xts)

set.seed(42)

# init data
datetimes <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2022-01-01"), 
                 to = as.POSIXct("2022-01-08"),
                 by = "10 mins")

values <- length(datetimes) |> runif() |> sin()

data <- xts(x = values,
            order.by = datetimes)

# 
ep <- endpoints(data, "days")

data_max <- period.apply(data, INDEX = ep, FUN = max)

head(data_max)
#>                          [,1]
#> 2022-01-01 23:50:00 0.8354174
#> 2022-01-02 23:50:00 0.8396034
#> 2022-01-03 23:50:00 0.8364624
#> 2022-01-04 23:50:00 0.8376930
#> 2022-01-05 23:50:00 0.8392988
#> 2022-01-06 23:50:00 0.8372780
```

Obviously, this would not work with summarizing functions like `mean` and `median` where you would want to specify the interval width considered, but when working with e.g. `min` and `max`, how would I proceed when I wanted to know the exact index of the value in question observed.

At the moment, I'm just looping over my xts subsets to determine the relevant index, but maybe there is a more elegant approach, maybe even an argument when using `period.apply()` I haven't noticed to get this information.

```r
sub <- "2022-01-04"

ind <- which(data[sub] == max(data[sub]))

data[sub][ind]
#>                         [,1]
#> 2022-01-04 23:20:00 0.837693
```

My desired output would look like this:

```r
#>                          [,1]
#> 2022-01-01 03:40:00 0.8354174
#> 2022-01-02 15:00:00 0.8396034
#> 2022-01-03 05:10:00 0.8364624
#> 2022-01-04 23:20:00 0.8376930
#> 2022-01-05 02:50:00 0.8392988
#> 2022-01-06 06:40:00 0.8372780
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `where you would want to specify the interval width considered`? - which I took to be `ep`...

Comment: @Chris: Oh, sorry, I might have misphrased that. My line of reasoning was that if I wanted to determine the mean temperature/humidity/whatever, you would only be able to tell the period (to, from) considered. Timestamps associated with means/sums follow certain conventions: e.g. to the left or right of the interval, sometimes centered, dependent on the resolution (10-minutely values vs. monthly values) chosen. In case of min/max you would be able to determine the exact timestamp of the observation because `max(data) %in% data`. But yeah, width is `ep` in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Use `ave` and subset that down to the rows with the maxima.  The last line takes the first maximum in each day and could be omitted if there are no duplicate maxima within a day such as for a strictly increasing input or if all maxima were desired. The `format` is to avoid time zone problems.

```
library(magrittr)
library(xts)

data %>%
  subset(ave(., as.Date(format(time)), FUN = max) == .) %>%
  subset(ave(., as.Date(format(time)), FUN = seq_along) == 1)
##                          [,1]
## 2022-01-01 03:40:00 0.8354174
## 2022-01-02 15:00:00 0.8396034
## 2022-01-03 05:10:00 0.8364624
## 2022-01-04 23:20:00 0.8376930
## 2022-01-05 02:50:00 0.8392988
## 2022-01-06 06:40:00 0.8372780
## 2022-01-07 08:40:00 0.8406546
## 2022-01-08 00:00:00 0.2335385
```

**2)** Another possibility is to aggregate using tapply with which.max to get the time of the first maximum in each date and then subset the data to those times.

```
data %>%
  subset(time %in% tapply(time, as.Date(format(time)), \(x) x[which.max(.[x])] ))

##                          [,1]
## 2022-01-01 03:40:00 0.8354174
## 2022-01-02 15:00:00 0.8396034
## 2022-01-03 05:10:00 0.8364624
## 2022-01-04 23:20:00 0.8376930
## 2022-01-05 02:50:00 0.8392988
## 2022-01-06 06:40:00 0.8372780
## 2022-01-07 08:40:00 0.8406546
## 2022-01-08 00:00:00 0.2335385
```

Comment: Nice! Weirdly, the first approach seems to drop all `%H:%M:%S` information when I run your code, but the second one works as intended. Seems like there are still lots of functions out there in the wild I'm not familiar with yet. Thanks!

Comment: Have fixed (1).

Comment: Can confirm, returns same output as (2) now - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using your data and inserting some NAs

```
set.seed(42)
datetimes <- seq(from = as.POSIXct('2022-01-01'),
to = as.POSIXct('2022-01-09'), by = '10 mins')


values <- length(datetimes) |> runif() |> sin()
ep <- endpoints(data, 'days')

values[which(1:length(values) %% 10 == 0)] <- NA
data <- xts(x = values,
   order.by = datetimes)

data_max <- period.apply(data, INDEX=ep, FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE)
> data[which(data %in% data_max == TRUE)]
                         [,1]
2022-01-01 03:40:00 0.8354174
2022-01-02 15:00:00 0.8396034
2022-01-03 05:10:00 0.8364624
2022-01-04 23:20:00 0.8376930
2022-01-05 02:50:00 0.8392988
2022-01-06 06:40:00 0.8372780
2022-01-07 08:40:00 0.8406546
2022-01-08 06:40:00 0.8411353
2022-01-09 00:00:00 0.8247520
```

Seems like `period.apply` is the way to go, and index of 'moment' can be found. And helps to use the same time period `01` -> `09`, not `10`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work with "real life data", especially if you're dealing with measurements of low precision where you might reach a certain value (e.g. 90 % humidity) multiple times a week. My bad for providing garbish reprex data with unique values only.

Comment: Well, any of the above answer the data as presented. Now, another question to address desired results from 'real life', preferably meteorological data, potentially extended by `xtsAttributes` (for something for me to wrap my head around).

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. I just should have considered this and put more effort in the data sample. Sorry for that and thanks nevertheless for your answer!

Comment: And I think you'll find `xtsAttributes` potentially interesting (originally designed for financial markets tseries), but could be applied to sampling stations, and relaxing `unique` in `xts(` ... And knew nothing about till reading this morning, and xts becomes much more interesting.

Comment: Yup, attributing all relevant information - who, what, when, how, etc. - associated with timeseries is quite handy and `xts` really is great for handling all of this, from my previous personal experience. Can recommend! :)